# ¿Por qué esta función para contar el número de lineas de un archivo siempre me devuelve 1?

Tags: c++

necesito saber el número de elementos que tiene un archivo de texto concreto, para copiarlo a un vector de strings, he creado esta función para ello pero siempre me devuelve 1, y no encuentro donde puede estar el fallo.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int CuentaLineas(void);

int main (void)
{
  cout << CuentaLineas;
  return 0;
}

int CuentaLineas (void)
{
  ifstream fichero;
  string linea;
  int i;

  i=0;
  fichero.open("palabras.txt");

  if (fichero.is_open()==false) cout << "Error al abrir el archivo. ";
  else
  {
    while (!fichero.eof())
    {
      while (getline(fichero, linea)){
        i++;
      }
    }
    fichero.close();
  }

  return i;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! donde crees que estas pasando linea por linea el archivo a algun lado?

Comment: Estas seguro que tiene mas de una linea? es decir tienes " \n" en alguna parte del archivo?

Comment: no quiero pasar el archivo a ningun lado en esta función, solo quiero contar cuantas lineas tiene

Comment: Si @FranIslas , es una lista muy larga con muchas palabras

Comment: No llamas a la función, creo... ¿no debería ser `cout << CuentaLineas()`? Te faltan los paréntesis en la llamada. Ahora... ¿por qué eso sale 1? Misterio...

Comment: Como dice @abulafia , el error está en que no estas ejecutando la función

Comment: Cierto, MUCHÍSIMAS GRACIAS!!!

Comment: Acuerdate de marcar la pregunta como resuelta para que si alguien tiene la misma duda la pueda resolver fácilamente. Y gracias a ti por preguntar!!

Comment: Cómo se hace? no veo la opcion por ninguna parte @ÁlvaroOrdunaLeón

Comment: Tienes el ejemplo aquí: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas
Como la respuesta no te la he dado yo en el comentario de abajo, deberías realizar un comentario tu mismo con el código modificado (el que te funciona) y marcarte a ti mismo la respuesta correcta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454/qu%C3%A9-hacer-en-caso-de-que-el-op-publica-en-comentarios-o-en-la-pregunta-misma-la

Comment: Para llamar a una función que se no te olvide poner los paréntesis al final del nombre. Si no solo estarías haciendo referencia a ella

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no lees cada una de las líneas. Simplemente compruebas que no has llegado al final del fichero y entonces aumentas en una unidad el valor de `i`.  Para poder hacerlo correctamente, basta con que en el bucle leas cada una de las líneas:

```
while (getline(fichero, linea)) {
    i++;
}
```

La función `getline` de `std` permite leer un `ifstream` por líneas, siendo que cuando alcance el final del fichero está función devolverá `null`, lo que se evaluará a `false` por lo que se terminará el bucle y pasarás a cerrar el fichero.

Comment: Buenas, he puesto lo que me has mandado y me sigue devolviendo 1, ya no sé que hacer

Comment: @Souni que es lo que has puesto exactamente en el código?

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int CuentaLineas(void);
int main (void)
{
    cout<<CuentaLineas;



    return 0;
}




int CuentaLineas (void)
{
    ifstream fichero;
    string linea;
    int i;

    i=0;
    fichero.open("palabras.txt");

    if (fichero.is_open()==false) cout << "Error al abrir el archivo. ";
    else
    {
        while (!fichero.eof())
        {
            while(getline(fichero, linea)){

            i++;}
        }
            fichero.close();
    }

return i;

}`

Comment: Perdona, no sé como ponerte el código para que puedas leerlo bien.

Comment: Voy a editar el post principal.

Comment: Escribo el comentario para que te salga la notificación  @Álvaro Orduna León

Comment: @ÁlvaroOrdunaLeón Antes de la edición Souni tenía `fichero >> linea` ¿no servía eso también para leer una línea?

Comment: Pues yo tenía entendido que si, pero parece que no. La verdad es que no se por qué pero probando el nuevo código del post principal (corrigiendo la llamada a la función con `()`) no cuenta bien el número de líneas...

Comment: A mi me da 22222, no es correcto? @ÁlvaroOrdunaLeón

Comment: No tengo el fichero `palabras.txt` así que no se :)
Pero con un fichero que le he creado a mano, no me contaba bien